# what are glib dependencies ( libs required to install glib)

Tags: software-installation

Can anyone inform me what are the dependencies of glib i.e that what libraries are need ( should be installed first) in order to install glib.

Comment: How are you trying to install glib?

Comment: There is no package named **glib**, there are just glib based libraries, install whichever you need.

Answer (score 0):

The dependencies are explained [in the glib manual](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.42/glib-building.html).